# Algorithm for optimal combination of virtual machine storage across multiple disks

Tags: algorithm, optimization, storage

I have a pool of data consisting of a computer name and the amount of disk space each machine takes up in GB.  I am looking for an algorithm that can take this data and put them in groups that combined gets as close to 650 GB as possible (optimal combination).  It seems much like the knapsack algorithm except that everything is weighted the same.

In the real world, my data is virtual machines that are living on a single large LUN.  I'm trying to break that LUN up into multiple smaller LUNs that are 1 TB in size but only want to store up to 650 GB on each LUN due to the need for growth as well as buffer space so that size alarms are not triggered.  I'm mixing large and small machines together and they range fro 9 GB up to 300 GB. Just trying to optimize storage from my data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like the CoinChange problem.

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change

You need to find all possible combinations of machines that add up to 650 GB

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to understand it is through analysis the Bin packing problem, as your virtual machines are the bins, etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: I think you're right in that bin packing seems to fit my problem but the LUNs are the bins and the VMs are the items to be placed in the bins.  However, I was just given another constraint.  In addition to the bin size of 650 GB, I can only have 15 items in a bin regardless of their size.  There are a total of about 200 items (VMs) in my data set.  Does anyone think that the new constraint changes anything?